# apache RewriteRule gets 404 Not Found error

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, httpd.conf

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/user     http://localhost/actions/login.php [R,L]
```

http://localhost/actions/login.php exists.

But for http://localhost/user it gets error:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /user was not found on this server.
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Have you tried to replace http://localhost/actions/login.php with actual domain name? Also, how do you add rewrites, in apache config file or via .htaccess? Do you have nginx enabled as a proxy server?

Comment: a2enmod rewrite, that's how i enabled rewrite module. I'm using apache, not nginx or nginx is not enabled as a proxy server.

Comment: What is actual domain?

Comment: If I understand correctly, there is no domain name for website yet, like example.com.
Try to put rewrites you have into .htaccess file to Document root of the website.